# Where does sqlite store the database file on win7 offline?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sqlite

I'm following [this](https://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/amp/), using js in html to call 'openDatabase("AddressBook",....'. It works, it stores values and calls them them back correctly when I reopen the page but I can't find where the AddressBook DB file is. I've searched my pc, C:\ and appdata etc but I can't find it. I've tried downloading the sqlite3 tool and setting a DB separately and transporting it to the folder but it doesn't seem to recognize it. If I change the name of the DB called it starts a new one and if I then put the previous DB name it shows the stored DB from before. I'd like to know I can locate it and transport it before I learn anymore.

Can anyone advise where it might be?
Is there a way to force it into the same folder as the js files?

Comment: That is not a valid link.  I tried to fix your link.  Please check and make sure I pointed it to the right place.  It looked like that was the URL it was trying to point to.

Comment: @zero298 that's the right page, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That guide seems seems to misunderstand the APIs that it is using.  It keeps saying that its using `SQLite`.  It's not.  It looks like it is using the deprecated `WebSQL` spec.  The file isn't in your filesystem, it's part of the browser's internal storage and there is no guarantee of how the browser is actually storing it so you can't directly access it from outside the browser.

I'm making the assumption that it is using WebSQL because it mentions using  `openDatabase` and `executeSql`.  WebSQL has been deprecated and is no longer maintained in most browsers.  You can get a detailed reasoning from this answer [Why is Web SQL database deprecated?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/220254/73574).  That guide you're following is also 9 years old and doesn't even discuss WebSQL's deprecation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it makes sense now